# Trigger charge in Android phone using a PIR

Tags: usb, charger, android

I want to use my android phone + 1 PIR as a poor man's home alarm. I need the phone to be triggered somehow when the PIR detects motion.

I was looking at the IOIO board. But wouldn't even be easier to just:

- monitor the "ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" event in android
- connect a USB cable to the android phone
- connect the PIR, a charger + pullup resistor as in:

[image]

When the PIR detects movement, it "switches" Ground on the USB cable to Ground on the charger, triggering the "ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" on android.

Would it work?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it should. In practice, it depends on the actual phone design, and your setup. You can always invert the PIR output if it's not logic high. But a better idea is simply using a motion detecting camera app. Then it's all just coding.

Comment: a motion detecting camera app will see nothing in poor lighting conditions... and the phone would discharge in a couple of hours.

Comment: It should be easy to add some IR LEDs, and your original design did include a power supply.